# tmux if-shell vs run-shell

Tags: shell, tmux

I don't understand why this code is not working equivalently between tmux `if-shell` and `run-shell`.

`is_not_leftmost` is true if the current tmux pane is not the leftmost. And if so, then we allow the key to select the next left pane.
The below works for the `if-shell` but not for the `run-shell`. In the `run-shell` version, I can never select the left pane no matter what current pane I'm in, so I think it might be a problem with the bash evaluation of `$is_not_leftmost`.

```
is_not_leftmost="[ $(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_at_left}') -ne 1 ]"

# Comment out one of the below
bind -n C-h if-shell "$is_not_leftmost" "select-pane -L" "" # works
bind -n C-h run-shell "if [ $is_not_leftmost ]; then tmux select-pane -L; fi" # doesn't work
```

What is the problem with the `run-shell` version?

Comment: Where did you define `is_not_leftmost`? If this is a typo for `is_leftmost`, you are trying to nest brackets, which doesn't work because brackets aren't syntax. `[` is a command with a mandatory final `]` argument. `[ [ $(tmux ...) -ne 1 ] ]` is not a valid shell command.

Comment: @chepner Yep, that was the issue - thanks! You can post that as the answer. (And I edited the post to fix the `is_not_leftmost` typo).

Comment: We *do* have existing Q&A entries around attempts to nest `[` (though admittedly  it was a bit tricky to find one).

Comment: @chepner could you take a look at this new question. It seems like a similar problem, and not sure what's wrong this time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707794/tmux-if-shell-run-shell-different-outputs